# kubernetes - expose app on a single endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm a beginner at kubernetes and looking to build a setup locally (on minikube) where the frontend pod (react app) fetches values from the backend pod.

The frontend application is a built react app which contains the static files.
The backend is a python app exposed on port 5000.

The frontend yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fe-nginx
  labels:
    app: fe-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fe-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fe-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fe-nginx
        image: fe_img:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fe-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: fe-nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Backend yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: be-python
  labels:
    app: be-python
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: be-python
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: be-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: be-python
        image: be_app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: be-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: be-python
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Being a react app when the frontend app, it's the browser that makes the request from the values to the backend pod. What's the best approach to make this work on a single endpoint ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you have the backend and the frontend as part of the same deployment? And then exposing the lone deployment using a single service with different ports?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually add endpoint object?

```
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.0.2.42
    ports:
      - port: <PORT>
```

You may also refer on this link for other details regarding [Pod set up as Network Service.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)